# Índice Indefinido - PHP

Tags: php, get, php-7

Em meu código PHP, mesmo com o MySQL e Apache ligados, aparece o erro

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ store \ add-product.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: preco in C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\adiciona-produto.php on line 5

Acredito que pela mensagem esteja falando da requisição do tipo GET, peguei o meu código e pelo o que vi ele não possui erro. Como eu poderia arrumar o código?

Código:

```
<?php include("cabecalho.php"); ?>
        <?php
        $nome = $_GET["nome"];
        $preco = $_GET["preco"];
        ?>
           <p class="alert-sucess">
            Produto <?= $nome; ?>, <?= $preco; ?> adicionado com sucesso!
           </p>
<?php include("rodape.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Você sabe o que o `$_GET["nome"]` faz? Conseguiria me explicar com suas palavras de maneira sucinta?

Comment: Acredito que sirva para armazenar os dados do "usuário" digitados pelo usuário, no caso o nome do produto descrito por ele.

Comment: E onde ficam esses dados? De onde o PHP puxa os valores dessa variável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ store \ add-product.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: preco in C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\adiciona-produto.php on line 5

Estes erros estão dizendo que o [tal] "índice" não está definido. Propriamente dito, sua variável `$_GET` não tem a chave `name` e `preco`.

Quando vc roda esse *script*, deve passar esses valores via *URL*.

Exemplo: `http://projetoromano.com.br/index.php?nome=Romano&preco=1.99`

> Fonte: [PHP - $_GET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php)

Finalmente:

> Como eu poderia arrumar o código?

Verificando **se os valores foram passados** e, caso não, o valor passa a ser "vazio":

```
<?php include("cabecalho.php"); ?>
    <?php
    $nome = $_GET["nome"] ?? 'vazio';
    $preco = $_GET["preco"] ?? 'vazio';
    ?>
       <p class="alert-sucess">
        Produto <?= $nome; ?>, <?= $preco; ?> adicionado com sucesso!
       </p>
<?php include("rodape.php"); ?>
```

O operador de coalescência nula (`??`) foi lançado no *PHP 7* e seria o mesmo que `isset($_GET["nome"]) ? $_GET["nome"] : 'vazio';`

> Fonte: [PHP - Novos recursos](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php)

Answer (score -1):

Então o código do amigo realmente certo, porem apresenta uma falha pra quem não quer passar nada na variável, porque quer usar na própria pagina como por exemplo um código de paginação onde você cria uma variável mas de incio você não passa nenhum valor na URL ah não ser que clic no botão, parece que não é nada mas se não presta atenção da dor de cabeça então vai a dica.

`<?php $nome = $_GET["nome"] ?? ''; // em vez de deixar a palavra 'vazio', não deixe nada $preco = $_GET["preco"] ?? ''; // em vez de deixar a palavra 'vazio', não deixe nada ?>`

Mesmo na Programação um espaço em branco ainda é alguma coisa é um valor, e no caso é um valor que não apresenta erro.